# How to use the output of a variable to call a vector in R

Tags: r

Hi can anyone help with this?
I'm trying to call a vector with a variable.  For example?

```
var <- 'apple'
apple <- c(1,2,3)
```

but now say I have a bunch of vectors like `apple` and I write a function where I'm just given the `var` variable. How can I access the `apple` vector with `var`?  I tried `eval(var)` but that does not achieve what I want.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

use `get`

```
get(var)
# [1] 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use `eval(parse(text=var))`.

Answer (score 2):

As @mnel notes, you can use `get`. However, there is probably a better way to go about this using `list`s.

If you make a `list` called say `fruit` like:

```
apple <- 1:3
orange <- 4:6
pear <- 7:9

fruit <- list(apple=apple,orange=orange,pear=pear)
#$apple
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$orange
#[1] 4 5 6
#
#$pear
#[1] 7 8 9
```

Then you can call the elements of `fruit` using the names you have in `var` like so:

```
var <- "apple"

# get the whole list element named "apple"
fruit[var]
#$apple
#[1] 1 2 3

# get the contents of the list element named "apple"
fruit[[var]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

If `var` had several different fruit names listed, it also works:

```
var <- c("apple","orange")
fruit[var]
#$apple
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$orange
#[1] 4 5 6
```

Comment: oh I see - clever, this will come in handy, almost reminds me of hashes in PERL